# The fundamental group of torus bundle

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, mapping-class-groups

A [torus bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_bundle) is labeled by an element $M$ of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ -- the mapping class group of a torus. How to compute the fundamental group of a torus bundle from the 2-by-2 matrix $M \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$? Any references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search on "fundamental group of a mapping torus" gives many hits - eg:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/fundamental-group-of-mapping-torus?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the section on monodromy in [my old preprint (Rigidity of Fibering, arxiv.org 1106.4595.)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4595)